# rimraf: missing path when ngh --dir=dist/path

Tags: angular, github-pages

I posting a question because im tired of this.

I again (5th time a day) have issue when trying build and deploy my angular app to git hub pages.

Build by command works fine and files are generated.
There is a command:
`ng build --configuration production --base-href "my-url-there"`
But when I try to:
`--dir=dist/path`
I got this:

```
❌ An error occurred when trying to deploy:
rimraf: missing path
```

And I don't know why, because I only editing my app (components etc.) and app works fine locally and also builds without any issues.

Somebody can help me to fix and prevent future issues with that, because I still don't know how to fix it out. Sometimes I achieving that but sometimes like today, im clueless.

I tried every previous method but now without any results.

I also tried to checkout last working and deployed commit and try to do it again on that, but result is the same.